# Ext-GWT Advanced Form

Tags: java, gwt, gxt, form-post

I'm attempting to use the [advanced forms](http://extjs.com/examples/explorer.html#advancedforms) of Ext-GWT, but the provided example is only shows how to lay out the form, not submit or process data. Are there any end to end examples of how to use these? I'm attempting to make a form that has text and a file upload, but I have no idea how to do anything beyond what is provided out in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in that form do this:

```
panel.setAction(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "UploadServletHere");
panel.setEncoding(FormPanel.Encoding.MULTIPART);
panel.setMethod(FormPanel.Method.POST);
```

And then somewhere in the form where you submit your form (clicking button) add this:

```
panel.submit();
```

Also make sure you make right HttpServlet where you can dissect your request in to different fields.

For more information of how to submit form you can  look at [THIS](http://extjs.com/examples/explorer.html#fileupload) example.